# Let $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$ and $a+b+c+ab+bc+ca = 1+a b c$. Prove that:

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c \in (0,1)$ and $a + b + c + a b + b c + c a = 1 + a b c$. Prove that:

$\displaystyle\frac{1+a}{1+a^2} + \frac{1+b}{1+b^2} + \frac{1+c}{1+c^2} \leq \frac{3}{4}(3+\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: $\frac{1+a}{1+a^2}+\frac{1+b}{1+b^2}+\frac{1+c}{1+c^2}$

Comment: Perhaps the notation $\sum_{cyc}$ for [cyclic sum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum) could be also appropriate in this case, but $\frac{1+a}{1+a^2}+\frac{1+b}{1+b^2}+\frac{1+c}{1+c^2}$ looks better, in my opinion.

Comment: Since you accepted the edit, I removed my comments.

Comment: of course, it 's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $a=\tan A,b=\tan B, c=\tan C$

So, $\tan(A+B+C)=1\implies A+B+C=\frac{\pi}{4} $ .

Now, $$\frac{1+a}{1+a^2}=\frac{1+\cos2A+\sin2A}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt2\sin(2A+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}$$

If $x=2A+\frac{\pi}{4}$, as $0<A<\frac{\pi}{4}\implies \frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$

If $f(x)=\sin x,f'(x)=\cos x, f''(x)=-\sin x<0$ as $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$

So, $\sin x$ is [concave function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConcaveFunction.html) in $(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4})$.

So using [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),

$$\sum \sin(2A+\frac{\pi}{4})≤3\sin\left(\frac{2A+\frac{\pi}{4}+2B+\frac{\pi}{4}+2C+\frac{\pi}{4}}{3}\right)$$
$$=3\sin\frac{5\pi}{12}=3\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{3(\sqrt3+1)}{2\sqrt2}$$

So,
$$\sum\frac{1+a}{1+a^2}=\sum\frac{1+\sqrt2\sin(2A+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin(2A+\frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$≤\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{3(\sqrt3+1)}{2\sqrt2}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3(\sqrt3+1)}{4}=\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}+\frac{9}{4}$$

Alternatively,  $$\frac{1+a}{1+a^2}=\frac{1+\cos2A+\sin2A}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt2\cos(2A-\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}$$

If $y=2A-\frac{\pi}{4}$, as $0<A<\frac{\pi}{4}\implies -\frac{\pi}{4}<y<\frac{\pi}{4}$

If $f(y)=\cos y,f'(y)=-\sin y, f''(y)=-\cos y<0$ as $-\frac{\pi}{4}<y<-\frac{\pi}{4}$

So, $\cos y$ is [concave function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConcaveFunction.html) in $(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$.

So using Jensen's inequality,

$$\sum \cos(2A-\frac{\pi}{4})≤3\cos\left(\frac{2A-\frac{\pi}{4}+2B-\frac{\pi}{4}+2C-\frac{\pi}{4}}{3}\right)$$
$$=3\cos(-\frac{\pi}{12})=3\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{3(\sqrt3+1)}{2\sqrt2}$$ and so on.

Comment: but how can we know ?
$$tanA+tanB+tanC+tanA.tanB+tanB.tanC+tanC.tanA=tanA.tanB.tanc+1$$ and $tan(A+B+C)=\pi$

Comment: $\frac{a+b+c-abc}{1-ab-bc-ca}=1$, right?

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: @lab: May I direct your attention to [$\TeX$/$\LaTeX$/MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), especially point 2. on displayed equations and the answer on [aligned](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5024) equations? This might improve readability of your answers which often feature somewhat complicated expressions in inline mode.