# Tricky geometry proof

Tags: geometry, inequality

If a,b,c belong to the interval $(0,1)$ and $ab + ca + bc = 1$, prove that 
$$\frac{a}{1-a^2} + \frac{b}{1-b^2} + \frac{c}{1-c^2}\ge\frac{3^{3/2}}{2}$$

How would you go about solving such a problem?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is there anyway to use it from an iPad?

Comment: Already edited it.

Comment: Did you click on the link I provided?  Can you type on your iPad?

Comment: Somehow I tried with $a=1/2$, $b=2$ and $c=0$ and I found $-5/6<0$. However $a=b=c=1/\sqrt3$ works. Could you please correct the interval, it is for sure not $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Corrected it, sorry. It's 1, not pi

Comment: @user34304 Yes, you can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on an iPad. MathJax is really just some sequence of characters (eg. `$\frac{3}{2}$`), and you can enter them on an iPad just as well on a computer.

Comment: @user34304, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194114/let-a-b-c-in-0-1-and-abcabbcca-1a-b-c-prove-that  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545107/three-variables-inequality-with-abc-abc

Comment: did you saw my answer? would you mind accepting it if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let that $x,y,z$ are the angles of a triangle, such that:
$$a=\tan(x/2),b=\tan(y/2),c=\tan(z/2),$$
You might be knowing these properties about a triangle:
$$\tan(x/2)\tan(y/2)+\tan(y/2)\tan(z/2)+\tan(z/2)\tan(x/2)=1$$
Which is given in question.Also:
$$x+y+z=\pi$$
By the way, maximum value of an angle evident from question is $\pi/2$, so that it is an acute triangle.Left Hand Side ( LHS ) of the inequality converts to this using the property
$$\frac12(\tan x+\tan y+\tan z),\quad\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=\tan2x$$
Now maybe you can minimize this.
You can also use this property of a triangle:
$$\tan x+\tan y+\tan z=\tan x\tan y\tan z$$
So LHS of the inequality becomes $$\frac12\tan x\tan y\tan z$$

---

**Hint:** 
By some symmetry reasons minima must occur at the point when all angle are equal,i.e. $x=y=z=\pi/3$.Putting values:
$$\frac12(\sqrt3+\sqrt3+\sqrt3)=\frac12(\sqrt3\sqrt3\sqrt3)=\frac32\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way: $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(ab+bc+ca) =3 \implies s=\dfrac{a+b+c}3 \ge \dfrac1{\sqrt3}$.

Now use $t \mapsto \dfrac{t}{1-t^2}$ is convex and Jensen's inequality to get
$$LHS \ge 3\frac{s}{1-s^2} \ge \frac{3\sqrt3}2=RHS$$